# Com o 9º dígito nos telefones, como posso resolver o problema da exibição de telefones que têm 8 dígitos?

Tags: php, mysql

Essa foi uma dúvida que me surgiu com a notícia do nono dígito nos telefones aqui no Brasil.

Tenho no sistema uma lista de telefones que são salvos, juntamente com o DDD.

Como eu poderia fazer para um telefone com 8 dígitos (e com o DDD) possa ser preenchido com o 9?

Exemplo de como está salvo no banco de dados:

```
(31)9915-2855
```

Como eu poderia transformá-lo em `(31)99915-2855`

**Observação**: Aceito soluções tanto em PHP como em MySQL.

Comment: Só lembre-se que nem todos os telefones no brasa já tem o nono digito. =)

Comment: Mas em Minas Gerais parece que vai ter. Então vai ter um _If gambiarra_

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Se todos os números estão com essa formatação, é possível utilizar `substr_replace()` para adicionar o `9` na quinta posição da string.

```
<?php
    $str = '(31)9915-2855';
    $novo = substr_replace($str, '9', 5, 0);
    echo $novo;
```

Saída:

```
(31)99915-2855
```

Comment: +1 Você é o cara. Nunca usei essa função na minha vida de PHP!

Comment: Depois de um `if (strlen($telefone) == 14)` posso fazer isso, para validar se é novo ou antigo - gambiarra

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, da pra resolver com `substr()` ou transformar a string em um array, o melhor seria se o ddd estivesse separado do número, ai é so usar `str_pad()`.

Answer (score 9):

Você pode usar esta instrução

```
UPDATE telefone 
SET celular = Replace (celular , '(31)', '(31)9')
WHERE celular REGEXP '\\(*31\\)*9[[:alnum:]]{3}-*[[:alnum:]]{4}$';
```

assim evita que atualize números de telefones que **não são números de celular** e que porventura **já contenham o nono dígito**

A instrução WHERE captura números que contenham ou não máscara, porém o `UPDATE`só funciona caso o valor esteja com **(31)9** *(sem espaço entre ')' e o 9)*

Para atualizar números armazenados em outros formatos modifique o `REPLACE`

Comment: Excelente, resposta melhor que a minha!

Answer (score 7):

A nível de banco, e só pros telefones de Minas, da pra fazer a seguinte solução:

```
UPDATE telefone 
SET    telefone = ( Replace (telefone, '(31)', '(31)9') )
```

Assumindo, é claro, que o campo `telefone` seja uma string, e que todos os telefones tenham o mesmo formato. Ah, e que o campo se chame `telefone` mesmo.