# Formatar números de telefone com 9 e 8 dígitos

Tags: php

Quero formatar números de telefones para os seguintes formatos:

(XX) XXXX - XXX = 11 2222 3333

Mas como alguns números novos vêm com DD + 9 dígitos, por exemplo:

(XX) XXXXX - XXXX = 11 22222 3333

Como formatar de forma a preencher os espaços vazios com zeros ou pela quantidade de algarismos e formatar de forma automática?

Comment: Vem do banco esses valores? está tudo junto? tem uma [pergunta parecida](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92506/91)

Comment: SIm, eles são armazenados no banco todos juntos, ex: 1122223333

Comment: Formatar no back-end ou em um `<input>` front-end?

Comment: Back-End, coloquei a tag de php rs

Comment: No exemplo dessa pergunta ele assume que todos comecem com 9, mas como eu vou pegar o valor do usuário, pode não ser exatamente esse, entende... acho que com algo com regex seria bom.

Answer (score 7):

Verifique a quantia de caracteres na string se 10 é necessário adicionar o nono digito do contrario não.

```
<?php
    function formataTelefone($numero){
        if(strlen($numero) == 10){
            $novo = substr_replace($numero, '(', 0, 0);
            $novo = substr_replace($novo, '9', 3, 0);
            $novo = substr_replace($novo, ')', 3, 0);
        }else{
            $novo = substr_replace($numero, '(', 0, 0);
            $novo = substr_replace($novo, ')', 3, 0);
        }
        return $novo;
    }

    $str = '1122223333';
    echo formataTelefone($str);
```

Saída:

```
(11)922223333
```

Comment: E como seria a formatação? (XX) ZZZZZ - YYYY

Comment: @ngthm4r3 o ddd é outro campo na tabela?

Comment: Não, vem tudo junto, 00111112222

Comment: @NGTHM4R3, faltou alguma coisa?

Comment: Foi mal, não tinha visto que você editou a resposta, vou testar, Obrigado!

Comment: Isso, qualquer avise. @NGTHM4R3

Comment: Opa, Obrigado pelo código, achei essa função aqui e implementei desse jeito:

http://pastebin.com/c0gj92ix

Fonte: http://blog.clares.com.br/php-mascara-cnpj-cpf-data-e-qualquer-outra-coisa/

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 boa também.

Answer (score 6):

Sei que a pergunta é antiga, mas se alguém ainda estiver precisando:

```
protected function formatPhone($phone)
{
    $formatedPhone = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $phone);
    $matches = [];
    preg_match('/^([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4,5})([0-9]{4})$/', $formatedPhone, $matches);
    if ($matches) {
        return '('.$matches[1].') '.$matches[2].'-'.$matches[3];
    }

    return $phone; // return number without format
}

return $this->formatPhone('11987654321');
return $this->formatPhone('1187654321');
```

Answer (score 3):

```
function telephone($number){
    $number="(".substr($number,0,2).") ".substr($number,2,-4)." - ".substr($number,-4);
    // primeiro substr pega apenas o DDD e coloca dentro do (), segundo subtr pega os números do 3º até faltar 4, insere o hifem, e o ultimo pega apenas o 4 ultimos digitos
    return $number;
}
```

Acho que é a forma mais facil

Comment: Funcionou perfeito aqui! Obrigado!

Comment: Desta forma é bem mais simples e o formato é melhor. Fica como (99) 99999 - 9999 ou (99) 9999 - 9999. Obrigado!

Comment: sim, simples e super eficiente, validos para celular ou nao

Answer (score 2):

```
 static public function masc_tel($TEL) {
    $tam = strlen(preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $TEL));
      if ($tam == 13) { // COM CÓDIGO DE ÁREA NACIONAL E DO PAIS e 9 dígitos
      return "+".substr($TEL,0,$tam-11)."(".substr($TEL,$tam-11,2).")".substr($TEL,$tam-9,5)."-".substr($TEL,-4);
      }
      if ($tam == 12) { // COM CÓDIGO DE ÁREA NACIONAL E DO PAIS
      return "+".substr($TEL,0,$tam-10)."(".substr($TEL,$tam-10,2).")".substr($TEL,$tam-8,4)."-".substr($TEL,-4);
      }
      if ($tam == 11) { // COM CÓDIGO DE ÁREA NACIONAL e 9 dígitos
      return "(".substr($TEL,0,2).")".substr($TEL,2,5)."-".substr($TEL,7,11);
      }
      if ($tam == 10) { // COM CÓDIGO DE ÁREA NACIONAL
      return "(".substr($TEL,0,2).")".substr($TEL,2,4)."-".substr($TEL,6,10);
      }
      if ($tam <= 9) { // SEM CÓDIGO DE ÁREA
      return substr($TEL,0,$tam-4)."-".substr($TEL,-4);
      }
  }
```

#### como usar:

```
echo self::masc_tel('5512123456789');
```

Comment: Esclareça sua resposta, acrescente outros detalhes para destacar como resolveu e a forme que propõe a solução. Se quiser mais informações de como responder, acesse [answer].

Answer (score 0):

Eu uso assim.

```
    function clean_char($string) {
        return preg_replace('/\D/', '', $string);
    }   

    function telefone_format($tel) {
        $tel = clean_char($tel);
        if(empty($tel)){
            return " Nenhum"; //OPCINAL
        }
        $telcheck = substr($tel, 0, 4);
        if (strpos($telcheck, '0300') || strpos($telcheck, '0800')) {
            preg_match('/(\d{4})(\d{3})(\d{4})/', $tel, $matches);

        //RETORNO 0800 355 1234
        return $matches[1] . " " . $matches[2] . " " . $matches[3];
    }
    if (strpos($tel, '4007')) {
        preg_match('/(\d{4})(\d{4})/', $tel, $matches);

        //RETORNO 4007 1234
        return $matches[1] . "-" . $matches[2];
    }
    $telcheck = substr($tel, 2, 1);
    if (strpos($tel, '9')) {
        preg_match('/(\d{2})(\d{5})(\d{4})/', $tel, $matches);
        return "(" . $matches[1] . ") " . $matches[2] . "-" . $matches[3];
    }
    preg_match('/(\d{2})(\d{4})(\d{4})/', $tel, $matches);
    return "(" . $matches[1] . ") " . $matches[2] . "-" . $matches[3];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Função para 9 dígitos + DDD

```
function formataTelefone($numero){
   $formata = substr($numero, 0, 2);
   $formata_2 = substr($numero, 3, 5);
   $formata_3 = substr($numero, 4, 4);
   return "(".$formata.") " . $formata_2 . "-". $formata_3;
}
```

Formato saída: `(xx) xxxxx-xxxx`